# seamless DNXHR player

Tags: video, playback, dnxhr

I am looking for a player for DNxHR that will playback files seamlessly, as there is no brief pause between files playing. two files played back to back should play as though they are effectively one file. can someone recommend a good solution for this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Player like djv and vlc should be able to play dnxhr without issue. The pauses likely occur because of the reading-speed of the drive. If djv and vlc are still buffering while playing, try moving your footage to a faster ssd and try again.

Comment: they seem to play a single file fine, but I see a hiccup between files. from what I can tell I have plenty of drive speed. any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm. Could you elaborate on the "hiccup"? Does the program have to buffer when playing two videos back to back and switching from one file to another? In that case, I think that a programmer could actually help you more than the beautiful folks here.

Comment: I believe it is a buffering, but not entirely sure.

Comment: I'd leave this question open here but ask the same one on the stackexchange or a similar forum dedicated to programming. I'd guess that your chances are better there :)